# Is it possible in PHP to exit an included file through something like die()?

Tags: php, die

My main PHP file includes several PHP files. At the beginning of one of them I'm testing a variable. If it passes the test then I want the whole script to run, otherwise I want to exit. Is it possible or do I have to condition my entire script (and not use anything similar to `die()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, normally it is bad practice to just die() anywhere in a script. However if you have a background script for example and you just want to quit, you can use `die()` everywhere. A better approach is for example to throw an exception and catch it on a top level

Comment: But it appears that die() in my included scripts interrupts everything not just that particular script!

Comment: You cannot just interrupt the current script. I recommend you to use function calls. You can leave that function where you want and return to the callee. Or you use the other approach and throw an exception

Comment: Check condition on a page and forward it to another page based in true false condition